# How to access Attributes of an Object inside an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, attributes

```
var ppArr [];  // An Array filled with Objects
var ppSort []; // Empty Array
var i = 0; // Counter
for ( ; ; i++) // Increase "i"
if ( ... )  // does not matter here
{
     var ppInfo = { SortIndex : ppArr[i].SortIndex, PPCount : 1, SortedArr : newArray() };
     ppInfo.SortedArr.push(ppArr[i]);
     ppSort.push(ppInfo);

}
else { // Neither dose that part
 ... 
     }
}
```

https://repl.it/E4xO/19

Hello Guys,

i am having a problem with accessing an Attribute of an Object through an Array in  Javascript.

As you can see I am pusing the "ppInfo" objects into the empty Array called "ppSort".

How is it possible to access the SortIndex of this object?

I have tried the following :

- ppSort.ppInfo.SortIndex
- ppSort[i].ppInfo.SortIndex

I am not sure what else I could try. Am I doing something comlpetly wrong?
I can access the SortIndex with "ppInfo.SortIndex" but this object is changed after every run.

Thank you and best regards,

Comment: `ppSort[i].SortIndex`

Comment: Please make this a minimal re-create of your problem. Currently there are no objects in `ppArr` so we cannot judge why you cannot access its content's properties. (Also, fix you indenting: currently unclear what the structure of your code is intended to be.)

Comment: @Ori Drori It returns "undefined"

Comment: what is the use of `i=0` before for loop ? when does your for loop ends ??

Comment: @Mahi , i just made something quickly up. That's not the problem I am having with this code. I am about to do a minimal re-create.

Comment: @Richard here is the recreation. https://repl.it/E4xO/19

Comment: Please include the full details *in the question* (do not expect others to go to another site to review your re-creation).

Comment: @Wintersun what is the use of if condition inside for loop

Answer (score 0):

The 'undefined' you see is just repl.it telling you the code ran without returning any values or throwing any errors. If you try it in a browser or a different test environment such as jsfiddle.net, you won't see the 'undefined'. Ori already gave you the answer, but if you want to see it working:

```js
var ppArr = [];

ppArr[0] = {
  Code: "Test",
  SortIndex: 100
};

ppArr[1] = {
  Code: "Test",
  SortIndex: 200
};

var ppSort = [];


for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) // Increase "i"
{
  if (i < 2) // does not matter here
  {
    var ppInfo = {
      SortIndex: ppArr[i].SortIndex,
      PPCount: 1,
      SortedArr: new Array()
    };
    ppInfo.SortedArr.push(ppArr[i]);
    ppSort.push(ppInfo);

  }
}

var r1 = '1st value: ' + ppSort[0].SortIndex;
var r2 = '2nd value: ' + ppSort[1].SortIndex;

alert(r1 + '\n' + r2);
```